# Go equivalent for PHP's pack()?

Tags: go, binary, pack

In PHP, to encode binary data, such as integers, floats and so on, I'd do the following:

```
<?php

$uint32 = pack("V", 92301);
$uint16 = pack("v", 65535);
$float = pack("f", 0.0012);

echo "uint32: " . bin2hex($uint32) . "\n"; // 8d680100
echo "uint16: " . bin2hex($uint16) . "\n"; // ffff
echo "float: " . bin2hex($float) . "\n"; // 52499d3a
```

How can I bring this code into Go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you need to use a function such as `pack()` in a language where the types in `pack()` are already native types of the language itself?

To encode binary data you'd use the package [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/). To replicate your code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    byteOrder := binary.LittleEndian

    binary.Write(buf, byteOrder, uint32(92301))
    fmt.Printf("uint32: %x\n", buf.Bytes())

    buf.Reset()
    binary.Write(buf, byteOrder, uint16(65535))
    fmt.Printf("uint16: %x\n", buf.Bytes())

    buf.Reset()
    binary.Write(buf, byteOrder, float32(0.0012))
    fmt.Printf("float: %x\n", buf.Bytes())
}
```

([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TPP20dQmyA))

With that, it's fairly easy to get going encoding other data structures. You really just need to change the third argument of `binary.Write` to be of the data type you wish, and the function will do [all the magic](https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/binary.go#L244)!

Comment: Amazing answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but since I've been looking for the following myself, I thought it could help others here too.

For a direct equivalent of php's bin2hex(), you can do:

```
import "encoding/hex"

func bin2hex(str string) string {
  return hex.EncodeToString([]byte(str))
}
```